# Entity framework can't connect to new table but only when deployed to Azure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, azure, webdeploy

I am running Entity Framework 6.1.2 and I appear to have gotten myself into a bind.  I am using the Code First approach.

I had a web site using a single database with two tables working just fine, both locally and when deployed on Azure.  I then tried adding a new model and that's when things fell apart.  I gave up on code first migrations because after a few hours of reading and trying the numerous steps necessary inside the Package Manage Console (3 steps per db context), the generated migration files always came out wrong.  Usually empty, with no code at all in the Up()/Down() methods.

That's when I tried a manual approach.  First I tried deleting and re-creating the database on Azure.  At first I thought that worked, but for some odd reason only the two original tables were recreated by Entity Framework.  The new table, and the child table it EF automatically due to a nested class in the new model, were not created.

Out of frustration I created the two new tables manually by copying the SQL query for the new table and child table from the SQL Designer window, and then executing those two queries against the Azure server.  That worked and I did create the tables successfully on my Azure SQL server instance.  However, my web site code can not connect with the new table(s).  It can connect to the two "old" tables, but *not* the new one and its child table.

Remember, this code executes fine locally, but when run on Azure, any queries against the new table fail with the following vague error message:

"*ERROR: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.), Inner exception: The system cannot find the file specified.*"

I did add a new connection string for the new table, using the database context as the connection string.  As I said, everything works fine when run locally.  **But why is it failing when I run it on Azure?**

Failing that, if I delete the database on Azure and rec-reate again, is there a fool-proof way to make Entity Framework re-create **all the taables** on Azure during publish/deploy?

Here's the model for the new table I'm having trouble with:

```
public class ImageSearchResultWrapper : ModelsBase
{
    public ImageSearchResultWrapper()
        : base()
    {

    }

    [Index, StringLength(60)]
    public string SearchQuery { get; set; }

    public ImageResult ImageSearchResult { get; set; }
} // public class SearchResultWrapper

public class ImageSearchResultDBContext : DbContext
{
    public ImageSearchResultDBContext()
        : base("name=ImageSearchResultDBContext")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<ImageSearchResultWrapper> ImageSearchResults { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the connection string for it:

```
<add name="ImageSearchResultDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-TruxWebSite-20141228220711.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: show us the model and the connection string.

Comment: when you perform your deployment to azure, are you selecting the option to migrate the database to the latest version?  azure replaces the connection string for your LocalDB with the correct connection string for azure, but it doesn't automatically 'migrate' the database unless you specify.

Comment: @Robert please post the prod connection string, NOT the dev one

Comment: @zaitsman That's the rub.  There wasn't one.  I went into the Publish Web dialog and checked each table and the new table didn't have a connection string.  I'm guessing that when I first created the publish profile I was prompted for the production connection strings.  It appears that if you add a new table manually, then you have to go into the Publish Web dialog and for each new table, add the production connection string needed to connect to it.  Therefore, the publish operation didn't know what to replace the LocalDB conn. string with.  It works now.

Comment: @AndrewCounts This wasn't an update database issue but connection string issue.  Please see my reply to zaitsman and thanks.